Download txt file from within RStudio Posit Workbench that runs on a Unix system to local windows machine
I am running RStudio Posit Workbench in my Chrome browser and want to download programmatically a text file to my local windows machine.
I have tried
# File on Unix server
unix_file <- "/users/tables_figures/file.tex"
url <- paste("file://", unix_file, sep="")

# Destination on local Windows machine
local_file <- "C:/Users/myname/tables_figures/file.tex"

# Download the file
download.file(unix_file, destfile = local_file, mode = "w", method = "auto")

but that generates errors and warnings
trying URL '/users/tables_figures/file.tex'
Error in download.file(unix_file, destfile = local_file, mode = "w", method = "auto") : 
  cannot open URL '/users/tables_figures/file.tex'

In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(unix_file, destfile = local_file, mode = "w", method = "auto") :
  URL '/users/tables_figures/file.tex': status was 'URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL'

The Unix directory and file exist and I have read/write permissions. The local directory exists, too, and I have read/write permissions there as well.
Any suggestions how to make this work? I do not want to use the point-and-click menu-driven solution in Workbench to export a file even if that works well because the file is one of many and they frequently get updated. The few solutions proposed on SO are either of the point-and-click type or do not work for me.
Alternatively, I have tried
# Construct SCP command
scp_command <- paste("scp user@host_machine:'/users/tables_figures/file.tex' 'C:/Users/myname/tables_figures/'")

# Execute SCP command
system(scp_command)

and that works but I need to force it (click "STOP") to request my UNIX password. Any thoughts here?

You're not going to be able to write R code to do that. While RStudio Workbench may know it's running in a browser, R itself does not. It's running as a process on the server and has no access to your local file system. If you use the RStudio file explorer there is usually an option to download to your local machine but that is point and click. Browser security measures prevent you from being able to write files anywhere on a users computer. Official docs: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200713893-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files-in-RStudio-Workbench-or-RStudio-Server

Thank you for your comment. I have tried to work around the issue using the RStudio API command rstudioapi::exportFiles() but that doesn't seem to work.
What seems to work is scp but I get hung up on the password request. Any thought here would be great.

" Any thought here would be great" . You should update your question to focus on you scp problem. Don't expect readers to follow an ever extending trail of comments to understand your problem (-;! OK? You're likely to get more readers for your new question if you just go ahead and post a new question (and possibly delete this one). Good luck.
